# Change Permission Bits Google Cloud Functions

Tags: go, google-cloud-functions

I create a function to get data from SQL database using SSL in Go 1.13 and upload these files

[image]

So I set the connectionString to:

```
connString := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%s dbname=%s user=%s password=%s sslmode=verify-ca sslrootcert=%s sslkey=%s sslcert=%s", os.Getenv("HOST"), os.Getenv("PORT1"), os.Getenv("DBNAME"), os.Getenv("USER"), os.Getenv("PASSWORD"), "pathto/server-ca.pem", "pathto/client-cert.pem", "pathto/client-key.pem")
```

I think the connectionstring is right, but then i got an error like this:

> pq: Private key file has group or world access. Permissions should be u=rw (0600) or less

is there a way to modify the permission bits in Cloud Functions file?

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve this, the files are not mutable. The solution is to copy it in the `/tmp` directory

```
    f, err := os.Open("pathto/client-key.pem")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()

    d, err := os.Open("/tmp/client-key.pem")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer d.Close()

    _, err = io.Copy(d, f)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    err = d.Chmod( 0600)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
```

And then use the `/tmp/client-key.pem` instead of `pathto/client-key.pem`

Comment: unfortunately, this operation is not permitted. It shows error `chmod pathto/client-key.pem: operation not permitted`

Comment: Indeed. I don't find any solution than copy the file into the `/tmp` directory and change it